# Android Wear not waking screen

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I'm working on a watch face and its up and running but when I put it on my 360 it becomes slow to respond to interactions.

I should note that the screen wakes when a notification is received but not when one turns their wrist to look at the time.

Last thing I did was move code out of doWork and into CountDownRunner. Below is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Date;

public class ClockActivity extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clock);

    Runnable runnable = new CountDownRunner();
    Thread myThread = new Thread(runnable);
    myThread.start();

    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });
}

class CountDownRunner implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            try {
                Date dt = new Date();
                int hours = dt.getHours();
                int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                String curTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

                img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hand_second);
                RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation((seconds-1)*6, seconds*6,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                        0.5f);

                rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

                img.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try{

                        }catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not implement `Runnable` to change time on your wearable. Use `BroadcastReceiver` (`Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK`, `Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED`, `Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED`) and receive a "tick" when time change (consumes less battery power and CPU).

Moreover, you must managed screen states (screen dim, screen awake, etc.)

Here is a great exemple of Watchface for Android Wear: http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/how-to-create-a-custom-android-wear-watch-face/120

And a last tips, you can manage seconds for your watchface only when your wearable is awake (like postdaleyed but must be killed when your wearable go back to sleep mode).

Comment: So I updated it all but now I cant seem to get the seconds hand working again. I have only tested on the emu until I get everything up and running. Check the code? http://pastebin.com/RzmJ5vCW

Comment: With BroadcastReceiver method, your method updateUI() is only called when minutes changes (prevent memory leak when wearable devices is not awake). You can add runnable script when wearable screen wake up to update seconds animation and you remove this runnable when wearable screen come off. Update seconds while the screen is off use a lot of cpu then a lot of battery ;)