# Android Analog Watch Second Hand w/ BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I can't figure out why startAnimation(); is not firing. This used to run on Runnable but I've moved to BroadcastReceiver. This was related to my previous question:

[Android Wear not waking screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350122/android-wear-not-waking-screen/26377111)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class ClockActivity extends WatchFaceActivity {

private ImageView img;

private final static IntentFilter INTENT_FILTER;
static {
    INTENT_FILTER = new IntentFilter();
    INTENT_FILTER.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    INTENT_FILTER.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
    INTENT_FILTER.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
}


private BroadcastReceiver mTimeInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        updateUI();
    }
};


@Override
public void onScreenDim() {
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onScreenAwake() {
    updateUI();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clock);
    updateUI();

    mTimeInfoReceiver.onReceive(ClockActivity.this, null);
    registerReceiver(mTimeInfoReceiver, INTENT_FILTER);

}

private void updateUI() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.hand_second);
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation((seconds-1)*6, seconds*6, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    img.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```

}

Comment: Instead of using a `RotateAnimation`, use `ViewPropertyAnimator`s instead. They are more efficient and a lot easier to use.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Do you have an example I could be pointed to?

Comment: I posted an example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a RotateAnimation, use ViewPropertyAnimators instead. They are more efficient and a lot easier to use. Something along the lines of this should work:

```
imageView.animate()
    .setDuration(1000)
    .rotation((360f / 60f) * calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND))
    .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

Comment: Are you sure the `updateUi()` method is being called?

Comment: I call in through the onCreate but whats a good way to double check?

Comment: Add a log at the beginning of the `updateUi` method and see if the log gets printed out in `logcat`. Also dont call `updateUi` directly from `onCreate()` and don't call `mTickReceiver.onReceive` directly from `onCreate` either. Just wait for the system to broadcast a tick event and eventually the system will call the `onReceive()` method for you.

Comment: Ive updated but now seconds run too fast and then stop and freeze. Can I PM you? Here is the current build: http://pastebin.com/h8vWJqtA